# MySQL LEFT Join issue - what am I doing wrong?

Tags: mysql, left-join

I should note that `id` is not unique in the tdemog_pfp table - there is a unique field there that auto-increments - could this be an issue?

Ok, I have the following SQL query:

```
SELECT id, name, total_staff AS StaffCount, COUNT( q60a ) AS TotalResp, (COUNT( q60a ) / total_staff * 100) AS Perc 
FROM tdemog_pfp
LEFT JOIN tresults_pfp ON tdemog_pfp.id = tresults_pfp.q60a
GROUP BY name
ORDER BY name
```

Now, the demog table has multiple rows where entries can have q59, q60a, q60b and so on for the colomn `qnum`

I want to bring back the results `WHERE qnum = q60a` but I have a problem, when I add it to the above to make the following - it brings back zero results (an empty result set), which is incorrect:

```
SELECT id, name, total_staff AS StaffCount, COUNT( q60a ) AS TotalResp, (COUNT( q60a ) / total_staff * 100) AS Perc 
FROM tdemog_pfp
LEFT JOIN tresults_pfp ON tdemog_pfp.id = tresults_pfp.q60a
    WHERE qnum = q60a
GROUP BY name
ORDER BY name
```

Where am I going wrong?

Thanks,

H.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make your test part of the JOIN condition instead of testing in the WHERE clause.

```
SELECT id, name, total_staff AS StaffCount, COUNT( q60a ) AS TotalResp, (COUNT( q60a ) / total_staff * 100) AS Perc 
FROM tdemog_pfp
LEFT JOIN tresults_pfp ON tdemog_pfp.id = tresults_pfp.q60a
    AND qnum = q60a
GROUP BY name
ORDER BY name
```

Comment: Thanks - now that brings back all the rows in the tdemog_pfp table - I just wanted the rows that equate to q60a?

Comment: @Homer_J: Are you trying to match a literal `'q60a'`? should that be enclosed on quotes? `AND qnum = 'q60a'`

Comment: @Jo - yep, tried with and without, still brings back all the rows in tdemog_pfp :-(

Comment: @Homer_J: Joe means `WHERE qnum = 'q60a'`

Comment: OH GOD - It is sooo one of those days....thanks @ypercube.  I am suitably embarrased...

Answer (score 1):

Doing this:  `WHERE qnum = q60a` is transforming your query into an `inner join`; hence, no results in this case.

Comment: Hmm, ok - suggested solutions?

Comment: @Homer_J hmmmm.... Don't do an inner join? or Did you try adding the condition in the left join as so: `LEFT JOIN tresults_pfp ON tdemog_pfp.id = tresults_pfp.q60a and qnum = q60a` removing the where clause, obviously.

Comment: Yup - brings back all rows in tdemog_pfp?